# Архитектура классов

Tags: c#, архитектура, uml

Есть примерно следующая инфраструктура классов:

[image: Архитектура классов приложения]

Почти все классы должны уметь возвращать некоторый ID.

Код возвращения ID-шника одинаковый везде, выглядит примерно так:

```
protected readonly int _id;

public int Id
{
    get
    {                
        return _id;
    }
}
AGetId(int id){ 
    if(id <= 0) throw new Exception("Exception!");
    _id = id;
}
```

Т.е. логично выделить этот код в некоторый абстрактный класс, от которого остальные классы должны наследоваться.

**Вопрос** в следующем: существует ли возможность указать в интерфейсе (или каким-либо другим способом), что класс, который имплементирует интерфейс, должен также наследоваться от этого абстрактного класса?

Comment: А что мешает создать абстрактный класс и наследоваться от него? Ну кроме того что множественного наследования нет

Comment: Зы. Вообще логика у вас ну очень странная. В геттере выбрасывать исключение? откуда у вас вообще берется невалидное поле только для чтения. Такие поля можно инициализировать только в конструкторе, вот в конструкторе вы и должны выбросить исключение. Геттер - это то место, от которого ну уж никак не ждешь исключения...

Comment: @Андрей ничего не мешает, просто в каждом классе необходимо будет  наследовать абстрактный класс и интерфейс (-ы), а если это забыть сделать - получиться ошибка. С геттером понял ошибку и поправил, спасибо.

Comment: В интерфейсе такое указать не получится. А в чем будет ошибка, если я создам еще один класс Person, который будет реализовывать интерфейсы и наследоваться от object?

Comment: Вы код изменили, но логичнее он от этого не стал (стал еще хуже). Еще раз - у вас поле `_id` имеет модификатор `readonly`, т.е его можно установить только в конструкторе экземпляра. Так и проверять его валидность значит надо в конструкторе. Лучше бросать исключение сразу при попытке создания невалидного объекта, чем потом при попытке использования бросать непонятные исключения.

Comment: @Vlad, ошибка в плане архитектуры (возможно я неправильно и непонятно выражаюсь), ведь большинство моих классов должны уметь возвращать Id, я хотел сделать так, чтобы создаваемые классы точно должны были наследовать данный абстрактный класс

Comment: Почему бы им тогда не реализовывать интерфейс `IGetId`?

Comment: @Ep1demic, ну сделайте вы абстрактный класс какой-нибудь `public abstract class BaseModel { int _id; public int Id { get => _id; private set { if (value <= 0) throw new Exceprion(...); _id = value; } } }` и наследуйтесь от него. В чем конкретно проблема? Вам нужно наследоваться от других классов?

Comment: @Vlad, потому что в таком случае нужно будет в каждом классе писать один и тот же код.

Comment: А кто мешает при реализации интерфейса наследоваться от `AGetId`? Какую задачу вы хотите решить? Если интерфейс должен реализовывать только наследник определенного класса, то это не интерфейс, а базовый класс.